# Checking which Google DoubleClick For Publishers (DFP) ad was served

Tags: google-dfp, mixpanel, double-click-advertising

I'm finding that some advertisers are over-aggressively reneging on ad impressions that have low viewability.  As a result, I'd like to do my own audit of viewability per ad, rendering only just as the ad scrolls into view.  I'll be tracking this with MixPanel, but was wondering if there is any way to insert a callback in the GPT API to determine which creative and line item was served after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Just listing this here for future searches:

`googletag.events.SlotRenderEndedEvent` seems be the best way to go about this as it provides access to several parameters including `creativeId` and the `LineItemId`.

**Full reference here** --> https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletageventsslotrenderendedevent